# How to block website popups using Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am making a website that mirror anthor webiste.

Just like the websites that make a mirror for piratebay , but it is for other website that blocked in my country.

The problem is, the website i need to mirror is full of popups windows which lead to some 18+ websites and i need to block all the popups using Nginx and dilver a clean version of that site to my visitors.

How i can do that using Nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your clients use [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy), you can inject [CSP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) into your response header to prevent inline and third party script/style sheet/frame to load.

If you want to modify it on-the-fly, use nginx's [substitution module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html), and change the pop-up script/frame source to `localhost`.

If you control your clients' DNS, just block it on your DNS server.